# What is the expectation of $X\sim \text{Exp}(\theta,1)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

Following this question:[Definition of $\text{Exp}(\theta,1)$ distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644922/definition-of-exp-theta-1-distribution).

The pdf of $X$ is given as $f(x,\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}$, $x>\theta$.

My question is, what is the expectation of $X$?

---

My work is that
$$
E[X]=e^\theta\int_\theta^\infty xe^{-x}dx=-e^\theta[\theta e^{-\theta}- e^{-\theta}]=1-\theta.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to recognize that $X$ is a location-transformed exponential distribution with location parameter $\theta$.  In other words, $Y = X - \theta$ is exponentially distributed with mean $1$.  How do we know this?  Well, because if $X$ has density $f_X(x) = e^{-(x-\theta)}$, then $Y = X - \theta$ will have density $$f_Y(y) = f_X(y+\theta) = e^{-(y+\theta-\theta)} = e^{-y}.$$  So we have
$$\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{E}[Y + \theta] = \operatorname{E}[Y] + \theta = 1 + \theta.$$
In fact, this reasoning easily generalizes to any location-scale transformation of a random variable:  if $X$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $Y = aX + b$ will have mean $a \mu + b$ and variance $a^2 \sigma^2$.

If we must do the integral calculation,
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[X] &= \int_{x=\theta}^\infty x e^{-(x-\theta)} \, dx \\
&= \int_{y=0}^\infty (y+\theta) e^{-y} \, dy & (\text{substitute } x = y + \theta, \; dx = dy) \\
&= \bigl[ (y+\theta)(-e^{-y}) \bigr]_{y=0}^\infty - \int_{y=0}^\infty (-e^{-y}) \, dy & (\text{IBP; } u = y + \theta, \; dv = e^{-y} \, dy) \\
&= \theta - \bigl[e^{-y}\bigr]_{y=0}^\infty \\
&= \theta + 1.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct. You have that for $X\sim Exp(\theta,\lambda)$,

$$
E[X] = \int_{\theta}^{\infty}xf_X(x)dx = \lambda e^{\lambda\theta}\int_{\theta}^{\infty}xe^{-\lambda x}dx
$$

Now, you solve the integral by partial integration (where you went wrong), which written out gives

$$
\int_{\theta}^{\infty}xe^{-\lambda x}dx = \left[x\left(-\frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{\lambda} \right) \right]_\theta^{\infty} + \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{\theta}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda x}dx = \frac{\theta e^{-\lambda \theta}}{\lambda}+\frac{e^{-\lambda\theta}}{\lambda^2} = \frac{e^{-\lambda\theta}}{\lambda^2}\left(\lambda\theta+1 \right)
$$

Plugging this into the expectation value gives

$$
 \lambda e^{\lambda\theta}\int_{\theta}^{\infty}xe^{-\lambda x}dx =  \lambda e^{\lambda\theta}\frac{e^{-\lambda\theta}}{\lambda^2}\left(\lambda\theta+1 \right) = \frac{\lambda\theta+1}{\lambda}
$$

So for $\lambda=1$, you get $E[X] = \theta+1$.